# redux does not fetch data in react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux, use-effect, mern

I have a problem in performing redux. I'm creating an app in which I create members through a route and upload their images through another route to MongoDb. When I want to fetch members and images based on each member name, I ran into the following error:

Here is how I fetch data:

```
const MemberList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const memberList = useSelector((state) => state.memberList)
  const { loading, error, members } = memberList

  const filesList = useSelector((state) => state.filesList)
  const { loading: uploadLoading, error: uploadError, files } = filesList

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listMembers())
    dispatch(listFiles())
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    <>
      {uploadLoading && <Loader />}
      {uploadError && <Message variant='danger'>{uploadError}</Message>}
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <>
          {members &&
            members.map((member) => (
              <MemberItem
                key={member._id}
                member={member}
                image={
                  files.filter((file) => member.name === file.name)[0].image
                }
              />
            ))}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

By

```
console.log(files.filter((file) => member.name === file.name)[0])
```

it returns the correct object, but

```
console.log(files.filter((file) => member.name === file.name)[0].image)
```

returns:

```
Cannot read property 'image' of undefined.
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when data is fetching, the value of `files` is the default value which you declare in the `redux-store`. I think you declare is an empty array: `[]`.

If `fetch listMembers` return value and `fetch listFiles` still running, your `console.log` will run with `files` is empty array: []. So files.filter(...)[0] is `undefined` and you recive this error

So, you can use `optional chaining` to check value, avoid same issue:

```
console.log(files.filter((file) => member.name === file.name)[0]?.image)
```